# asp.net An error occurred while doing the POST request. Details: Connection reset

Tags: asp.net, json, web-services

Using Asp.Net, I have created web Method.After that Published the Application to the IIS Server. The Web Method's Both Request and Response Types are Json. When I Testing that function error was occurred.

That error is **An error occurred while doing the POST request. Details: Connection reset**

Please help for this issue

Comment: Can you check the IIS logs?

Comment: Yes Mr.Webbanditten, But this don't have any usaeful information

Comment: Can you share it with us?

Comment: **2017-04-03 11:56:45 IP_Addr POST /PMSDEV/TripIBAPI/InstantBooking.asmx/booking_submit - 443 - 49.207.182.108 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/56.0.2924.87+Safari/537.36
https://gracebeta.com/PMSDEV/TripIBAPI/InstantBooking.asmx?op=booking_submit 500 0 64 517
2017-04-03 12:00 IP_Addr POST /PMSDEV/TripIBAPI/InstantBooking.asmx/booking_submit - 443 - 49.207.182.108 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/56.0.2924.87+Safari/537.36 - 200 0 0 2053**
This above Lines are in the IIS LogFile